# Is there a way I can bind mount dot files from a windows host to a linux container?

Tags: linux, windows, docker, containers, mount

I am attempting to mount a file from my **Windows** (Host) to my **Linux** (Container). When I mount a single file with a standard extension, everything seems to work fine. However, when I attempt to mount a single file that is a dot-file, it does not work.

```
//This does not work
type=bind,source=${env:USERPROFILE}\\.sample,target=/home/.sample,consistency=cached

// This does work
type=bind,source=${env:USERPROFILE}\\sample.txt,target=/home/sample.txt,consistency=cached
```

I'm not sure how to specify that the file is a dot file. I did notice that if the file did not exist, a folder named **.sample** was created on my Windows (Host) machine, but that same folder was not created on Linux (Container).

Comment: What is the error message you get (if any)? How did you check that the file/directory was not available in the container (exact command you used and output) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure they aren't there? Linux treats dotfiles as hidden files, so they aren't visible by just doing an `ls` command.

You can use `ls -A` which should show you the hidden dotfiles.

Comment: I feel a bit silly now, but that was it. It was binding, just not displaying in bash.